# Invalidating an access token for Google Drive using JS client

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Is there a way to make the access token received for Google Drive expire sooner than 1 hour? That would significantly speed up the testing process.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a request to revoke an access token or a refresh token:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke